# Accessing MYSQL through terminal

Tags: command-line, mysql, perl

I just installed LAMP in my computer through commandline.Now how can I access MYSQL prompt from commandline?I need to use MYSQL to create tables,views and then access them from my Perl script.

Comment: You dont have to access MySQL from command line if you dont want to.
You can use a tool like phpmyadmin, which is a tool that lets you manage your database in your browser.

Comment: You can still have to access MySQL from command line whether you want it or not. You can also use tools like phpmyadmin, mysql workbench, which let you manage your database in a GUI.

Answer (score 17):

To access mysql from CLI:

```
 mysql -u <username> -p<password> <database_name>
```

Make sure no space between `-p` and password. Of course, this password will be visible in history.

To overcome this:

1. Leave it blank and it will ask you for it.
2. start the command with a space in front of `mysql`

Comment: Are you sure it is not "--password={pwd}". If seem to remember the next word after -p is considered the database. But more important: this will echo the password into the process list and if you do not want this password stored in "history" add a space in from of "mysql" ;)

Comment: -p<password> no space in between. Edited the answer.

Comment: Oh yes! That was it indeed. It needs to be against the -p

Comment: Why on earth would they require the condition that there's no space between -p and password? I spent half an hour on this believing I was a victim of some black magic.

Answer (score 4):

With ...

```
mysql -u {user} -p {database}
```

The database is optional. {user} is the user you created when installing. You will get prompted for the password you supplied when installing. By the way: this is assuming you installed our native LAMP stack.

If you not yet have a user and password

```
mysql
```

will work too. If it does do make a user and password with correct privileges.

This is assuming MySQL is running.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) about MySQL command line Tool

And a [basic tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make sure the service has been started with:

`sudo service mysql start`

After that, if you have not set up any users or databases, then you could run:

`/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p`

to access the command line as root. If you set up a root password when installing LAMP then enter that. Otherwise just press enter and set the password later.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this from the terminal to login as root user:

```
sudo -s
```

enter your password;

then invoke mysql on the terminal

This is how it should appear like:

```
user_name@user_name:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for <user_name>: 
root@<user_name>:~# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Comment: You must not necessarily be root to invoke MySQL.

Comment: that is true, but if the problem persists, it is always better to login as root...mine works best that way.